# Failed to fetch - Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cors

I'm using Node JS Express for backend and plain HTML for frontend. On click of a button, I'm trying to send form data to MongoDB via Node JS.

Client [HTML]

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sendData();" id="get-marker-value" class="btn pxp-hero-contact-form-btn">Get Market Value</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function sendData(event){
                let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
                let address = document.getElementById("address").value;

                if(name != '' || email != '' || phone != '' || address != ''){
                    let formData = JSON.stringify({
                        name: name,
                        phone: phone,
                        email: email,
                        address: address
                    });
                    let url="<SERVER_URL>/listing/add_listing";
                    
                    fetch(url, {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: formData,
                        headers:{"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
                    }).then(response => response.json())
                    .then( (result) => {
                        console.log('success:', result);
                        $('#get-marker-value').addClass('hide');
                        $('#get-marker-value-success').addClass('show');
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        </script>
```

On the server side,

```
var listingRouter = require('./routes/listing');
app.use('/listing', listingRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" // what matters here is that OPTIONS is present
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Routes - Listing

```
router.post('/add_listing', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Post Request");
  console.log(req.body);
    const name = req.body.name;
    const phone = req.body.phone;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const address = req.body.address;
    const date = new Date();

    const newListing = new Listing({
      name,
      phone,
      email,
      address,
      date,
    });
    newListing.save()
      .then(() => res.json('Listing added!'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

The code is working fine in local, but having issues in Heroku.

Answer (score -1):

the url on the client side pointing to the localhost you need it to point to your heroku server

```
  let url="http://localhost:3000/listing/add_listing";
```

also check tutorials on how to use heroku
you also need to make sure that your database is connected to the heroku server
you can have more info here on how to deploy to heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app